# Differences between a quotient map and a continuous function in topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

Def. for a continuous function:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ 
>   is continuous if $f^{-1} (V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V \subseteq Y$.

Def. for a quotient map:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ be a set (that is not 
>   necessarily a subset of $X$). Let $p : X \rightarrow A$ be a surjective map. Define a subset $U$ of $A$ to be open in $A$ if and only if $p^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X$. The resultant collection of open sets in $A$ is called the quotient topology induced by $p$ , and the function $p$ is called a quotient map.

In addition to surjectivity of a quotient map, **are** there any difference**s** between this two concepts? From many different examples in comparison, they seem to be different 'topics' but actually no other difference more than surjectivity in case of a quotient map (?)

Also the book claims that a quotient map is always a continuous function.

Comment: A surjective continuous map $X\to A$ need not be a quotient map, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: In general, for a surjective continuous map $X\to Y$, there are subsets $M\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(M)$ is open although $M$ is not open.

Comment: A quotient map is always a surjective continuous function, by definition. But the class of continuous surjections is much broader than that of quotient maps.

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke: in latter comment "a quotient map is always a surjective continuous function" but in the first "a surjective continuous function may **not** be a quotient map". How does it work?

Comment: I got it! Thank you both.

Comment: I understand that quotient map is "stronger" than continuity but can anyone explain what is that quotient map can do which a surjective continuous map cannot do? In the definition what is special about "for any subset $U \subset Y, \; p^{-1}(U)=open \; \Rightarrow U$ is open "?